# Flurry throwing "GOOGLE PLAY SERVICES ERROR"

Tags: google-play-services, flurry, flurry-analytics

I am trying to integrate Flurry analytics into my Android app, and I am facing certain issues. I am seeing these errors in logcat every time my app starts:

```
E/FlurryAgent: GOOGLE PLAY SERVICES ERROR: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for the service connection
E/FlurryAgent: There is a problem with the Google Play Services library, which is required for Android Advertising ID support. The Google Play Services library should be integrated in any app shipping in the Play Store that uses analytics or advertising.
```

My app is not yet published on Google Play Store, might that be what's causing these errors?

By the way, Google recommends against including whole Google Play Services library: "Don't use the combined play-services target. It brings in dozens of libraries, bloating your application. Instead, specify only the specific Google Play services APIs your app uses."

That's why I included only Google Analytics (com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:17.0.0) which is mentioned in [Flurry documentation](https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/integrateflurry/android-manual/?guccounter=1). Tried also including Google Base Client Library (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.0.0) but I'm still getting those errors.

Any ideas?